# Ubuntu 18.04 thinkpad resumes from suspend immediately

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, acpi, pci

I have a Lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon 7th gen. When I enter suspend (by any method) the laptop wakes from suspend by itself. I noticed that this behavior only occurs when the laptop is docked (Lenovo USB-C gen2 dock), since I use my laptop docked 90% of the time it is important to get suspend working.

**Things I have tried:**

Disabling all PCI wakeup:

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

Then setting `echo <deviceHere> > /proc/acpi/wakeup` for all enabled devices (except `LID` so that I can resume by lid if needed)

Disabling all USB wakeup:

`cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup`

`ll /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup`

Then setting `echo "disabled" >  /sys/bus/usb/devices/<deviceHere>/power/wakeup` for all enabled devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there were two `PXSX` devices when running `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:05:00.0
```

When I tried to disable `PXSX` via command `echo PXSX > /proc/acpi/wakeup` then nothing happened (one `PXSX` stayed `enabled` and one stayed `disabled`, I assume this is because this command could not reach the second `PXSX`.

I also tried running `acpitool -w` then `acpitool -W <deviceNumberHere>` to disable the second `PXSX`, which was unsuccessful. I'm not sure why wake cannot be disabled on this second `PXSX` device.

This device only appears when the laptop is docked so it is safe to assume this device is part of the dock.

Next step was to somehow disable this device to stop it from waking the laptop. I found the command `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/remove` would disable this PCI device. After running this command, suspend worked correctly! The only problem is that if I tried to perform suspend again the laptop would exhibit the previous behavior (immediate wake). This was confirmed by running `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` to see that `PXSX` had re-enabled itself: somehow during wake the device was re-enabling itself.

My next idea was to disable this device during pre-suspend. I created this file: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/pre-suspend.sh`, made it executable and wrote these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  pre)
    echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/remove
    ;;
esac
```

This code ensures that the problem device will be disabled immediately prior to suspending. Currently, my laptop successfully sleeps without waking itself 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here, since I had a similar problem and the same computer.

My Carbon X1 has been working...all right, until all of a sudden, it refused to suspend.  In addition, CPU utilization was high - it got terribly hot and the fans were spinning at full speed, but nothing showed up with htop.  Running `powertop` confirmed something was going on, showing 'cpu core' as draining 13-20 W (normal for an idle computer is 3-5 W).  I tried to upgrade (from 20.10 to 21.04) to see if it would help - it didn't.

I tried giving `systemctl suspend` in the console, and that gave me some error messages about USB devices not being able to suspend properly.  Strangely, these messages don't show up in any logs, or in `journalctl`.

In the end, what fixed it for me was `rmmod`ing `xhci_pci` and `xhci_pci_renesas`.  Suddenly, CPUs idle down, fans follow suit, and suspend is working again.

Comment: On my Thinkpad T14, after disabling all devices in /proc/acpi/wakeup except for the sleep button (SLPB), I noticed that the laptop resumes the second I move it. Removing the `xhci_pci` and `xhci_pci_renesas` modules stopped this from happening. I suspect that an accelerometer must play a role in the unwanted resuming, but I don't know what it is exactly.